# $ C^p_0(B,\mathbb{X})$ is a Banach space with the norm of $C^p\!\!$-topology?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathbb{X}$ a Banach space with norm denoted by $\|\;\cdot\;\|_{\mathbb{X}}$. Let $ B $ the open ball with center at $ 0$ and radius $ r> $ 0, *i.e.* $B(0,r)=\{x \in \mathbb{X}: \|x-0\|<r\}$.
Let be $ C^p(B,\mathbb{X}) $ the set of applications $ u: B\to\mathbb{X}$ that are continuous together with its $i$-nth derivatives (in sense of [Fréchet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative)):
$$
\begin{array}{l}
B\ni x \longmapsto D^{(1)}u(x)\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{X},\mathbb{X})\\ 
\hspace{10mm}\vdots \hspace{14mm} \vdots  \hspace{18mm} \vdots\\
B\ni x \longmapsto D^{(i)}u(x)\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{X}^i,\mathbb{X})\\
\hspace{10mm}\vdots \hspace{14mm} \vdots  \hspace{18mm} \vdots\\
B\ni x \longmapsto D^{(p)}u(x)\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{X}^p,\mathbb{X}).\\
\end{array}
$$
 Here, $u: B\to \mathbb{X}$ is continuous with respect to norm $\|\;\cdot\;\|_{\mathbb{X}}$ in $B$ and $\mathbb{X}$. The  $i$-th derivative $D^{(i)}u:B\to\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{X}^i,\mathbb{X})$ is continuous with respect to norm $\|\;\cdot\;\|_{\mathbb{X}}$ 
 in $\mathbb{X}$ and norm 
$$
\|\;T\;\|_{\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{X}^i,\mathbb{X})}=\sup_{\eta_1,\ldots,\eta_i\in \mathbb{X}}\frac
{\|T \cdot (\eta_1,\ldots,\eta_i)\|_{\mathbb{X}}}
{\|\eta_1\|_{\mathbb{X}}\cdot\ldots\cdot\|\eta_i\|_{\mathbb{X}}}
$$
in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{X}^i,\mathbb{X})$.

Suppose $C^p(B,\mathbb{X})$ is endowed with the norm of $C^P$-topology  that is defined by
$$
\| u\|_{C^p}= \|u\|_0+\|D^{(1)}u\|_1+\ldots+\|D^{(i)}u\|_i+\ldots+\|D^{(p)}u\|_p
$$
where $\|u\|_{0}=\sup_{x\in B}\|u(x)\|_{\mathbb{X}}$ and 
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\|D^{(i)}u(x)\|_i
=&
\sup_{x\in B}\|D^{(i)}u(x)\|_{\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{X}^i,\mathbb{X})}
\\
&
\\
=
&
\sup_{x\in B}\;\;\sup_{\eta_1,\ldots,\eta_i\in \mathbb{X}}\frac
{\|D^{(i)}u(x)\cdot (\eta_1,\ldots,\eta_i)\|_{\mathbb{X}}}
{\|\eta_1\|_{\mathbb{X}}\cdot\ldots\cdot\|\eta_i\|_{\mathbb{X}}}
\end{array}.
$$

> **Question:** Let $C^p_0(B,\mathbb{X})=\{u\in C^p(B,\mathbb{X}) : u(0)=0 \}$.  $ C^p_0(B,\mathbb{X})$ is a Banach space with the norm  of $C^P$-topology? That is, $C^p_0(B,\mathbb{X})$ is a complete linear space with the norm $\|\;\cdot\;\|_{C^p}$?  Necessary $\|u \|_{C^p}<\infty$ for all $u\in C^p_0$.

Comment: Using only the $C^0$ part of the norm, you can show this is a closed subspace. (Also, there's something missing in your definition; you need to consider only $u$ with finite $C^p$ norm.)

Comment: @aes You mean you need to $\| u \|_{C^{\,0}}<\infty? $

Comment: I just mean you need the norm you defined to be finite, i.e. $\|u\|_{C^p} < \infty$. That part of the comment was a bit pedantic and was just referring to the fact that you defined $C^p$ before putting the norm on it, and the way you defined it may have included $u$ that don't have finite norm.

Comment: @aes It Would Be  $u$ is continuous with respect to norm $\|\;\cdot\;\|_{\mathbb{X}}$ and the  $i$-th derivative $D^{(i)}u(x)$ is continuous with respect to norm $\|\;\cdot\;\|_{\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{X}^i,\mathbb{X})}$?